# Does pthread mutex guarantee starvation freedom?

Tags: pthreads, mutex, starvation

### Background

I often stumble open cases where the order of lock acquisitions must be the same as real-time order of lock attempts. Those cases are usually about semaphore like locks.

### Theory

From what I read in "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming", deadlock freedom and first-come-first-served guarantees are sufficient to make the lock starvation free. Deadlock freedom seems to be on the users since they have to remember to unlock properly. I have looked at possible types of mutexes provided on the [pthreads manual page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html), but it doesn't seem to mention any ordering on lock acquisitions.

### Question

Does pthread mutex guarantee starvation freedom? Are there implementations that do (I'm mainly concerned about linux family and macOS)? Are semaphore guaranteed the same properties as mutex?